# Как найти противоречия в данных Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Я знаю, как удалить **дубликаты** строк из исходных данных в Pandas: `drop_duplicates`

Но при подготовке данных перед обучение НС может быть так, что в двух или более строках **признаки** **совпадают**,
а **предсказываемые значения отличаются**.
Например: (x1  x2  x3) -> **1**  и (x1  x2  x3)  -> **0**. 
Как обнаружить такие ситуации ?

И сразу встает вопрос, как их обработать?
Например, одну из строк **выбросить** - оставить только с 1. Как?

Или, взять **среднее**, т.е. такие строки убрать, а вместо них вставить одну со средним значением предсказываемого значения: (x1  x2  x3) -> **1/2**

Comment: Мне кажется тут от решаемой задачи зависит

Comment: подготовкa данных перед обучение НС

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Вопрос

Пусть есть такие данные, с повторениями в объектах:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    "feature1": [1, 1, 3],
    "feature2": [10, 10, 30],
    "target": [-1, -2, -3],
})

data.to_markdown()
```

```
|    |   feature1 |   feature2 |   target |
|---:|-----------:|-----------:|---------:|
|  0 |          1 |         10 |       -1 |
|  1 |          1 |         10 |       -2 |
|  2 |          3 |         30 |       -3 |
```

1. Как выбросить повторения, оставив только одну строку для каждого повторения?

```
|   feature1 |   feature2 |   target |
|-----------:|-----------:|---------:|
|          1 |         10 |       -1 |
|          3 |         30 |       -3 |
```

2. Как схлопнуть повторения, взяв среднее для каждой группы?

```
|   feature1 |   feature2 |   target |
|-----------:|-----------:|---------:|
|          1 |         10 |     -1.5 |
|          3 |         30 |       -3 |
```

3. Каким образом обычно разрешают такие ситуации с данными при подготовке к обучению нейросети?

### Ответ

Не имею достаточного опыта с нейросетями, но могу предложить возможные алгоритмы для выполнения первых двух пунктов.

1. Однострочное решение:

```py
dropped_data = data.iloc[data.drop(columns="target").drop_duplicates().index]
dropped_data.to_markdown()
```

```
|    |   feature1 |   feature2 |   target |
|---:|-----------:|-----------:|---------:|
|  0 |          1 |         10 |       -1 |
|  2 |          3 |         30 |       -3 |
```

Как это работает? Убираем колонку target из исходных данных (`.drop(columns="target")`), получаем таблицу

```
|    |   feature1 |   feature2 |
|---:|-----------:|-----------:|
|  0 |          1 |         10 |
|  1 |          1 |         10 |
|  2 |          3 |         30 |
```

Далее удаляем дубликаты (`.drop_duplicates()`), получаем таблицу

```
|    |   feature1 |   feature2 |
|---:|-----------:|-----------:|
|  0 |          1 |         10 |
|  2 |          3 |         30 |
```

Забираем индексы (`.index`): `[0, 2]`.

Используем `.iloc` для получения строчек начального датафрейма по индексам.

2. Однострочное решение:

```py
mean_data = data.groupby(list(set(data.columns) - { "target" })).mean().reset_index()
mean_data.to_markdown()
```

```
|    |   feature2 |   feature1 |   target |
|---:|-----------:|-----------:|---------:|
|  0 |         10 |          1 |     -1.5 |
|  1 |         30 |          3 |     -3   |
```

Как это работает? Выбираем колонки с признаками (`set(data.columns) - { "target" }`), группируем по ним (`groupby` принимает список, поэтому предварительно преобразуем в `list`), берем среднее от оставшихся колонок, получаем таблицу:

```
|         |   target |
|:--------|---------:|
| (10, 1) |     -1.5 |
| (30, 3) |     -3   |
```

После этого сбрасываем индекс (`.reset_index()`), чтобы вернуть значения из индекса в столбцы.